# PHP PDO passing variables in functions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im just making the move to PDO as suggested by a bunch of people on here :)

Here is the code that currently works

```
<?php
$table = "tbl_staff";
$all = $database->find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM tbl_staff'); echo '<pre>';
echo "<b> Find by SQL</b></br>";
print_r($all);
echo '</pre>';
?>

public function find_by_sql($sql) {
$this->query($sql);
$rows = $this->resultset();
return $rows;
}

public function query($query){
$this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

public function resultset(){
$this->execute();
return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function execute(){
return $this->stmt->execute();
}
```

So that all works as expected and returns all the tbl_staff details.

However i want to change the table name to pull the name from a variable like this

```
<?php
$table = "tbl_staff";
$all = $database->find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM "'.$table.'"'); echo '<pre>';
echo "<b> Find all rows </b></br>";
print_r($all);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

That returns a server error of Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"tbl_staff"' at line 1'

Ive tried just $table, '$table' and {$table} but it seems to read the line literally as $table and not replace with the variable. is there a different rule with PDO statements? Im a bit lost with getting to grips with PDO so apologies if this is a simple one

Comment: is this: SELECT * FROM tbl_staff the only query that you are using or are there other queries too ?

Comment: Remove the double quotes from around `$table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not evaluate variables used within single quotes, it treats them as literals. Use double quotes as follows:

```
$all = $database->find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM $table");
```

Also you had  extra quotes around `$table` like `"$table"` which would come off as:

```
select * from "tbl_staff"
```

hence the syntax error, and this is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the double quotes:

```
$all = $database->find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
```